# Were there any Roman Catholic Church martyrs in the 10–15th centuries?

Tags: catholicism, church-history, martin-luther, medieval-church, martyrdom

Do we know of any martyrs from among the Roman Catholic Church that lived during the five centuries before Martin Luther (i.e., 10–15th centuries)? I am especially interested in those who have been well-spoken of by Martin Luther.

Comment: There were definitely martyrs. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Christian_martyrs_by_century I'm not familiar enough with Luther to list any he thought particularly highly of.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**St. Thomas Beckett** - 1170 - assassinated at a church for annoying the king who made him Archbishop.

**St. Berard and companions (of Assisi)** - 1226 - killed by the Moors

**Bl. Charles the Good** - 1127 - killed at church after stopping black marketers

**St. Stanislaus** - 1079 - killed after excommunicating a wicked king.

**St. Elphege** - 1012 - killed by Danish invaders for refusing ransom by selling off his church property.

**St Adalbert** - 983 - killed evangelizing Prussians.

**St. Joan of Arc** - 1412 - (not canonized until 1920, but pardoned thirty years after her death) burned at the stake and not really a martyr, but I thought I'd throw her in here.

**St Wenceslaus** - 929 - killed by his brother while praying in a church.

**St. John Nepomucene** - 1390 - drowned in the Vltava by a very different King Wenceslaus for refusing to violate the Seal of confession.

I found these folks just by looking through my lives of the saints book there are undoubtably more. I haven't a clue about Luther's knowledge of these particular saints. However, I think it's safe to say that educated people knew about St Thomas Beckett and may have heard about Joan of Arc in Western Europe (From the Canterbury Tales and Joan of Arc is *now* the patroness of France). As in Eastern Europe they may have known of St. Wenceslaus and St Stanislaus (patrons of Czech Republic and Poland).  Their cults didn't operate in a complete vacuum.

Comment: Thank you Peter very much. Can you, please, tell me what the "neck of the woods" mean?

Comment: *Neck of the woods*: locality, area, especially one which is familiar because of residence.

Comment: @AndrewLeach thanks, I just realized how much of a recursively worthless idiom that might be!

Comment: How is Joan of Arc "not a martyr"?

Comment: @PeterTurner Why do you think everyone knew Thomas Beckett and Jean of Arc in 16th century? And why in Luther's region Wencelaus and Stanislaus? I come from the region Luther lived and today both have no special role. I think I first heard of St Stanislaus when I was in Krakow a few years ago.

Comment: @K-HB  I'd imagine Thomas Beckett and Joan of Arc were well known on account of what had been written about them (namely the Canterbury Tales and the account of Joan of Arc's trial).  St. Stanislaus is the patron of the country to your right and St. Wenceslaus is the patron of the country to your south.

Comment: @PeterTurner Luther was an educated man, so maybe that applies to him. But I fear you overestimate the horizon of normal people in the end of the middleages. BTW: When Luther studied in Erfurt he lived in the [Electorate of Mainz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electorate_of_Mainz) with the next "countries" beeing the lands of the [House of Schwarzburg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Schwarzburg) and the [Electorate of Saxony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electorate_of_Saxony). Boehmia and Poland were far away.

Comment: @k-hb yeah, I know that.  Before Luther codified German you guys couldn't even understand what people in the the village over was saying, right? All I'm saying is that it seems likely that when most people cared a bit more about their religion than they do today that they were acquainted with a few more of its heroes.

Comment: @PeterTurner Shall we move this conversation in chat?